# Is a number congruent to 1 mod 4 divisible by a number congruent to 3 mod 4

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am almost certain of the answer to this question, but cannot seem to find something to confirm it, and I feel the proof is too simple to be correct.  I have studied modular arithmetic a decent bit, but am too uncomfortable in the subject to feel confident in my answer.  If this is a duplicate I apologize and request to be directed to the correct answer.

The question: If a number is congruent to 1 mod 4, can it ever be divisible by a number congruent to 3 mod 4.  More specifically, for positive integers $a$ and $b$, we know $a \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod} 4)$ and $b \equiv 3 (\textrm{mod} 4)$.  Can $b | a$?

Comment: 3|9$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Right--take any number that's 3 mod 4 and square it.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample, for odd $n$:
$$a=3^{2n}, b = 3^{n}$$

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely simple.  Must just be a bit brain-dead right now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The product of two numbers congruent to $3$ mod $4$ is *always* congruent to $1$ mod $4$. For example, $3\cdot 7=21$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my favourite example: Take $a=57$, the Grothendieck's Prime!!